# Unicodes are not getting translated in java

Tags: java, unicode

I wrote the below code snippets and i'm expecting the output to be **Açılış Tarih/Saati:** but instead i'm getting **AÃ§Ä±lÄ±ÅŸ Tarih/Saati:** The code is as follows.

public class ResourceBundleTest {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {            
        try{
        String turkey = "A\u00e7\u0131l\u0131\u015f Tarih/Saati:";
        System.out.println(new String(turkey.getBytes("UTF-8")));
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("hello");
        }
    }

}
```

Please help me how can i get rid of this issue.

Answer (score 4):

This code is basically broken:

```
new String(turkey.getBytes("UTF-8"))
```

That:

- Starts with a string.
- Encodes the text as UTF-8.
- *Decodes* that binary data using the platform default encoding.

It's like saving an image as a PNG and then trying to load it as a JPEG.

You can try:

```
System.out.println(turkey);
```

... if that doesn't show up as you want it to, the problem is probably just that your console doesn't support those characters. Trying to change the encoding won't help at all - the *best* it could do (if you were really lucky) is to get back to the original string. More likely (and it seems this is the case with your output) is that the platform default encoding isn't UTF-8, so you're losing data.

Comment: i tried the approach you said but in that case i'm getting the o/p as "Aç?l?? Tarih/Saati:"

Comment: @SouravBag What OS are you using? Windows' `cmd.exe` does not handle unicode well.

Comment: @SouravBag: So you either need to change your console, or change your font, or just not use a console at all (e.g. create a Swing UI).

Comment: @JonSkeet this is happening in one of my portal application. While writing the property key values in the pdf, those junk characters are appearing. In my application i'm using tomcat6 application server where jdk version is 6. How can i solve this now?

Answer (score 1):

In `turkey.getBytes("UTF-8")` you explicitly create a byte-array containing the String contents encoded in UTF-8. However the contructor `String(byte[])` decodes, according to its documentation, this byte sequence using the system's default encoding. Which may not be UTF-8.

Why don't you just write `System.out.println(turkey)`, though? What's the point of encoding the String in UTF-8 and then decoding it before printing it?